# zkSNARKS: If we are already using Homomorphic Encryption/Hiding, why is the shift by $\delta$ required for Zero Knowledge?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

I am reading this explanation of zkSnark written by Maksym Petkus - http://www.petkus.info/papers/WhyAndHowZkSnarkWorks.pdf

From Section 3.5

> Because verifier can extract knowledge about the unknown polynomial
> $p(x)$ only from the data sent by the prover, let us consider those
> provided values (the proof): $g^p$, $g^{p'}$, $g^h$. They participate in
> the following checks:
>
> $g^p = (g^{h})^{t(s)}$ (polynomial $p(x)$ has roots of $t(x)$)
>
> $(g^p)^\alpha = g^{p'}$ (polynomial of a correct form is used)
>
> The question is how do we alter the proof such that the checks still
> hold, but no knowledge can be extracted? One answer can be derived
> from the previous section: we can "shift" those values by some random
> number $\delta$ (delta), e.g., $(g^p)^{\delta}$. Now, in order to
> extract the knowledge, one first needs to find $\delta$ which is
> considered infeasible. Moreover, such randomization is statistically
> indistinguishable from random.

We already have Strong Homomorphic Encryption (as stated in Section 3.3.3),

$E(v) = g^v \pmod n$

The $g^p$, $g^{p'}$, $g^h$ are created as above. I mean how do you extract info about p, p' & h from $g^p$, $g^{p'}$, $g^h$ that the shift by $\delta$ is required?

So then why is the $\delta$ shift required for Zero Knowledge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero-knowledge means *zero* knowledge, that we learn literally nothing except the validity of the proof.

Even if we don't learn $p, p'$ and $h$ themselves, we still learn $g^p$ which we could not have known before the protocol took place. So we have learned *something*, even if it isn't $p$.

Shifting by $\delta$ removes this leakage. Then we learn absolutely nothing, because the $g^{p\delta}$ completely hides $g^p$. As they say, "such randomization is statistically indistinguishable from random." If I gave you a random $X = g^x$, where $x$ is generated as $p\delta$ for a random $\delta$, you have no way of knowing anything about $\delta$ or $p$ (including $g^p$) from it.

Comment: Ok, got it. I guess it's like a using an IV or nonce in symmetric encryption to randomize so that the same input twice gives different output.

Comment: Yep, exactly :)